# I can't create Map with example

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

[I use example code. please see capture screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Phyj.png)

My code in react.

```
<Map center={position} zoom={13}>
  <TileLayer
  url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors" />
  <Marker position={position}>
  <Popup>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br />Easily customizable.</Popup>
  </Marker>
</Map>
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot it looks like you aren't including the necessary leaflet css. But I can't be 100% sure without seeing some code.

Comment: I think I forgot. u try add <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.5/leaflet.css"> to public/index.html, I still not work.